# Why tensorflow addons F1 Score gave 0 for correct guess?

Tags: tensorflow

I am confused. My goal is to train my CNN model with F1 Score. However, the result is weird

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
metric = tfa.metrics.F1Score(
    num_classes=4, threshold=0.5)
y_true = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    # [0, 1, 0, 0],
    # [1, 0, 0, 0]
], np.int32)
y_pred = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    # [0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2],
    # [0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
], np.float32)
metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
result = metric.result()
result.numpy()
```

The expected result is

```
[1,1,1,1]
```

So, when I want to get the macro F1 Score, it should be `1` instead of `0.25`.

The actual result is

```
[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

So, when I use parameter `average=macro`, the actual result is `0.25`.

EDIT:

I am confused. I add another row to `y_true`, and it works. I expected it to throws error but it does not.

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
metric = tfa.metrics.F1Score(
    num_classes=4, threshold=0.5)
y_true = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0]
    # [0, 1, 0, 0],
    # [1, 0, 0, 0]
], np.int32)
y_pred = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    # [0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2],
    # [0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
], np.float32)
metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
result = metric.result()
result.numpy()
```

Is tensorflow addons buggy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue with `tfa.metrics.F1Score`. You have defined 4 classes and each element of the `y_pred` row represents the class probabilities and its made 1 if its above the threshold, and then F1 score is computed. In your first example, there were no outputs representing classes 0,2,3, that's why they were zero.

Check the below example,

```
y_true = np.array([
    [0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],

y_pred = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0.6, 0, 0.51, 0],
#metrics.F1Score
[1.       , 0.6666667, 0.6666667, 0.       ]
```

Comment: the last column of y_true `[0], [1], [0]` and y_pred `[0], [0], [0]` -> is this how the package calculate class 3 f1 score? precision = 0 / 0 + 1, recall = 0 / 0 + 1, `f1score = 2 * 0 * 0 / (0 + 0)`

Comment: Yes, take the second column. y_true = [1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 1], here recall is 0.5, precision is 1.0 and so F1 is 0.666